# Forbiden to use urllib.request.urlretrieve to download an Excel file

Tags: python, web-scraping

I try to download a table from EMCSG website https://www.nems.emcsg.com/nems-prices.
It's working by typing below URL in web browser https://www.nems.emcsg.com/api/sitecore/DataSync/DataDownload?value=10&fromDate=2023-07-21&toDate=2023-07-21&tpcValue=1.

However, when I use Python code below to download the file, it returns me:

> "Download failed: Forbidden"

It might be blocked by web site for web scraping. Is there any way using Python to overcome this problem?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime 
import pytz
import urllib.request

def download_file(file_name):
    url = f'https://www.nems.emcsg.com/api/sitecore/DataSync/DataDownload?value=10&fromDate={file_name}&toDate={file_name}&tpcValue=1'
    file_path = f'raw data/omie_spain/{file_name}'
    try:
        # download file from url
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_path)
        print(f'Downloaded {file_name} successfully!')
        return file_path
    except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        print("Download failed:", e.reason)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # file_name_date = datetime.datetime.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")

    # get tomorrow's forecast
    # file_name_date = datetime.datetime.today() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    file_name_date = datetime.date(year=2023, month=7, day=20) 
    file_name_date = file_name_date.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
    file_name_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H%M")
    print(file_name_time)
    print(file_name_date)

  

    raw_file_name, formatted_file_name = f'{file_name_date}', f'{file_name_date}{file_name_time}.csv'
    raw_file_path = download_file(raw_file_name)
```

Below is result:

> 1653
> 2023-07-20
> Download failed: Forbidden

If also tried using `urlopen` method, it also returns me error below:

```
1651
2023-07-20
Traceback (most recent call last):
    urllib.request.urlopen(url,context=context)
  File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 216, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 525, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 634, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 563, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 496, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\urllib\request.py", line 643, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden
```

```
1645
2023-07-20
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XX\hello\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 467, in _make_request
    self._validate_conn(conn)
  File "C:\Users\XX\hello\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 1092, in _validate_conn
    conn.connect()
  File "C:\Users\XX\hello\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 642, in connect
    sock_and_verified = _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname(
  File "C:\Users\XX\hello\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py", line 783, in _ssl_wrap_socket_and_match_hostname
    ssl_sock = ssl_wrap_socket(
  File "C:\Users\XX\hello\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 469, in ssl_wrap_socket
    ssl_sock = _ssl_wrap_socket_impl(sock, context, tls_in_tls, server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\XX\hello\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py", line 513, in _ssl_wrap_socket_impl
    return ssl_context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
  File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 512, in wrap_socket
    return self.sslsocket_class._create(
  File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1070, in _create
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\XX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\ssl.py", line 1341, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XX\hello\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 790, in urlopen
    response = self._make_request(
  File "C:\Users\XX\hello\.venv\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 491, in _make_request
    raise new_e
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\XX\hello\.venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 486, in send
    resp = conn.urlopen(
    retries = retries.increment(
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, reason) from reason  # type: ignore[arg-type]
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.nems.emcsg.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/sitecore/DataSync/DataDownload?value=10&fromDate=2023-07-21&toDate=2023-07-21&tpcValue=1 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

  File "c:\Users\XX\hello\Dynamic_Tariff\emcsg.py", line 92, in <module>
    r = requests.get(url)
  File "C:\Users\XX\hello\.venv\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py", line 73, in get
    return request("get", url, params=params, **kwargs)
    return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\XX\hello\.venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 589, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\XX\hello\.venv\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py", line 703, in send
  File "C:\Users\XX\hello\.venv\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py", line 517, in send
    raise SSLError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='www.nems.emcsg.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/sitecore/DataSync/DataDownload?value=10&fromDate=2023-07-21&toDate=2023-07-21&tpcValue=1 (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trying to pull the csv file using the python requests library does work for me.
This is because the requests library does some stuff underwater to work around security measures some sites have taken for scraping.
To use urllib you need to add a user agent to the header.

```
headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.3"
}
```

Then in your code:

```
request = urllib.request.Request(url, headers=headers)
```

This will allow you to get the CSV file

Comment: this works fine for me, finally i'm able to get data, thanks                                            
         opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
        opener.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0')]
        urllib.request.install_opener(opener)
        urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, file_path)

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to download the file using `requests` and it works:

```py
import requests

url = 'https://www.nems.emcsg.com/api/sitecore/DataSync/DataDownload?value=10&fromDate=2023-07-21&toDate=2023-07-21&tpcValue=1'

with open('data.csv', 'w') as f_out:
    f_out.write(requests.get(url).text)
```

Creates `data.csv`:

```
"Date","Period","Demand (MW)","Solar (MW)","TCL (MW)","USEP ($/MWh)","EHEUR ($/MWh)","LCP ($/MWh)","RUSEP ($/MWh)","MAP ($/MWh)","MAPT ($/MWh)","TPC Applied","Last Updated"
"21-Jul-2023","00:00-00:30","5794.647","-","0.000","100.43","-0.45","0.00","100.43","127.29","534.75","No","21 Jul 2023 05:31:30 PM"
"21-Jul-2023","00:30-01:00","5684.482","-","0.000","100.37","-0.45","0.00","100.37","127.10","534.75","No","21 Jul 2023 05:31:30 PM"
"21-Jul-2023","01:00-01:30","5579.829","-","0.000","100.08","-0.43","0.00","100.08","126.98","534.75","No","21 Jul 2023 05:31:30 PM"
"21-Jul-2023","01:30-02:00","5535.024","-","0.000","100.26","-0.43","0.00","100.26","126.86","534.75","No","21 Jul 2023 05:31:30 PM"
"21-Jul-2023","02:00-02:30","5502.371","-","0.000","100.06","-0.42","0.00","100.06","126.87","534.75","No","21 Jul 2023 05:31:30 PM"
"21-Jul-2023","02:30-03:00","5462.890","-","0.000","96.27","-0.41","0.00","96.27","126.81","534.75","No","21 Jul 2023 05:31:30 PM"

...
```

Comment: thanks for checking and show it's running properly, I run same code but still return me SSL certifcate error, maybe it's due to by computer or python installation.

Comment: @jakeurey You can disable TLS verification with `requests.get(url, verify=False).text`. But I recommend to  install the correct certificates (this depends on operating system/used libraries/etc.)